# How do I prevent ProcessStartInfo's print verb from opening a window?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to print off a file generated in my application using the following code:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("Temp.txt");
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "print";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```

This works, and sends the file to the printer as expected. However, in the process, an instance of notepad opens for naught but a second. This is an application meant to run in the background, so those windows popping up are incredibly distracting.

Adding `pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` before the final line of the above snippet does help marginally. But still causes a brief, small popup - which drags the user out of any fullscreen application they may be in at the time.

Comment: Do you really need external application to print your data? Can you use `PrintDocument` ()https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 or other built-in tools for printing directly?

Comment: @Serg while that does work in terms of preventing any popups, the solution I have above would simply be easier to configure for the end user as it allows them to just open up notepad/whatever application is the default, and configure the printing settings there. doing it via PrintDocument would require significantly more effort in regards to loading configuration from file etc, even before considering something like handing line wraparound, unless there's something I'm missing from looking through the documentation and playing with it a little bit.

Comment: The pop-up that you're describing for Notepad, is a MessageBox with a title of "Notepad". It contains a message that states: Now Printing yourFilename.txt and contains a Cancel button. If you open Notepad and print a file, you'll see the same MessageBox.